# Windows background process

Tags: windows, process

In windows 2012 server, there is a background process which is associated with `svchost.exe` and has particular pid. This process has no associated services with it. How to check which files (probably .dll) are associated with it and maybe change something in them so that process will not start?

EDIT:
svchost.exe is sitting in c:\windows\fonts\svchost.exe
[image]

But when browsing to this dir it is not there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To list the many processes running under *svchost.exe*, examine them with Task Manager or Sysinterntals' [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

[image: Process Explorer showing *svchost.exe*]

Each application and its path is shown in detail.

Comment: Sysinternals showed svchost.exe sitting in  c:\windows\fonts, but it is not there.
Sysinternals sais image is probably packed